# Html Table Colspan Not showing as expected

Tags: html, html-table

I want To make This Layout as Below:

[image]

> First Row **colspan:3** is Showing as **colspan:2**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    
    <style>
     
    </style>


</head>
<body style="">
    
 

    <table width=200 border="1">

        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: red;" colspan="3">Red</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="background-color: green;" colspan="2">Green</td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td style="background-color: blue;" colspan="3">Blue</td>
        </tr>


    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

**I want to solve this with only Html**

It can be solved with by adding width but i don't want that.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want  the columns to all be of equal width?

Comment: @BillBell They want red and green to overlap, which currently isn't happening (tested in Firefox and Safari).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) CSS property, like this:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">

    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: red;" colspan="3">Red</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="background-color: green;" colspan="2">Green</td>
        <td></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td style="background-color: blue;" colspan="3">Blue</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much , I needed this output